# How to File i/o member functions, or overload <<operator?

Tags: c++, file-io, operator-overloading, member-functions

So I wrote my program to work in the command prompt first before trying to output it into a file. It works perfectly in the command prompt, but I run into major issues when trying to output member function data to the file. At the momemnt to circumevent this shortcomming i simply declared a int temp variable in main to store the get function values. then i fileout the temp value for each value that i need. However there is a function (define) that takes the length and width values and determines if it is a square or if it is a rectangle. This works just fine in the command line, but it will simply say everything is a square in the output file.

I have heard of a way of directly outputting member functions by overloading the (<< operator), but when i look at the example in the book i cant work out the syntax issues. If I were to be able to just write "box_out << wrap();" that would solve all of my issues. The wrap() function wraps all of the values into one statement and the displays the message.

So essentially what I am need help with is to either improve my file out statments, or to overload the << operator that would allow me to say box_out<

```
      /*
  c++ programming
  Asmt2
  box_new
  Takes in defined object parameters and user defined parameters and gives you the lenth width area parameter and whether or not it is a square.
  *-*-*Stand-alone file*-*-*
  */
  #include <fstream>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string>
  #include <cmath>
  using namespace std;

  class Rectangle{
    public:
      Rectangle();
      Rectangle(float len);
      Rectangle(float len, float wid);
      ~Rectangle();


      void setLength(float len);
      void setWidth(float wid);
      float getLength();
      float getWidth();
      float getPerimeter(void);
      float getArea(void);
      int define(float width, float length);
      void wrap();

      friend std::ostream &operator << ( std::ostream &, Rectangle & );
    private:
      float length;
      float width;
      float area;
      float Perimeter;

    };


    Rectangle::Rectangle(){
      setLength(1.0);
      setWidth(1.0);
    }

    Rectangle::Rectangle(float length){
      setLength(length);
      setWidth(1.0);

    }

    Rectangle::Rectangle(float length, float width){
      setLength(length);
      setWidth(width);
    }



      void Rectangle:: setLength (float len){
        if(len > 0.0 && len < 20.0){
          length = len;
        }else{
          cout << "\n*-*-*Invalid input setting to default setting of 1.0*-*-*"<<endl;
          len = 1.0;
          length = len;
        }
      }



      void Rectangle:: setWidth (float wid){
        if(wid > 0.0 && wid < 20.0){
          width = wid;
        }else{
          cout << "\n*-*-*Invalid input setting to default setting of 1.0*-*-*"<<endl;
          wid = 1.0;
          width = wid;
        }
      }


      float Rectangle:: getLength(){
        return length;
      }

      float Rectangle:: getWidth(){
        return width;
      }

      float Rectangle:: getPerimeter (void){
        getLength();
        getWidth();
        Perimeter = (2 * length) + (2 * width);
        return Perimeter;
      }

      float Rectangle:: getArea (void){
        area = length * width;
        return area;
      }

      int Rectangle:: define (float width, float length){
        if(fabs(width - length) < .0001){
          cout <<"You have a Square!"<<endl;
          return 1;
        }else{
          cout <<"You have a Rectangle!"<<endl;
          return 2;
        }
      }

      void Rectangle:: wrap(){
        cout << "The length is: " << length << endl << "The width is: " << width << endl;
        cout << "The box has a Perimeter of: "<< getPerimeter() << endl << "The box has an area of: " << getArea() << endl;
        define( length, width);
      }

      Rectangle::~Rectangle(){
        cout << "The object with a lenth of " << length << " and a width of " << width << " has gone out of scope. \n";
      }
      ostream &operator << (ostream &output, Rectangle &display){
            output << "Your lenth is: " << display.getLength()<< "Your width is: " << display.getWidth()
                   << "Your area is: " << display.getArea() << "Your Perimeter is: " << display.getPerimeter();
          }



  int main(void){

    ofstream box_out;
    box_out.open("box_out.txt");

    Rectangle box1;
    Rectangle box2(7.1, 3.2);
    Rectangle box3(6.3);
    Rectangle box4(30,50);
    Rectangle box5=box2;
    Rectangle box6;//user defined

  /*  float Perimeter = 0;
    float area = 0;
    float length = 0;
    float width = 0;*/

    float temp = 15;

  //first box
    cout << "*-*-*Your first box*-*-*\n";
    box1.wrap();
  //file output
    box_out << "*-*-*Your fist box!*-*-*";
    temp = box1.getLength();
    box_out << "   Your Length is: " << temp << "\n";
    temp = box1.getWidth();
    box_out << "   Your Width is: " << temp << "\n";
    temp = box1.define(box1.getLength(), box1.getWidth());
    if(temp == 1){
      box_out << "   You have a Square!";
    }else if(temp == 2){
      box_out << "   You have a Rectangle!";
    }
    temp = box1.getPerimeter();
    box_out <<"   Your Perimeter is: " << temp;
    temp = box1.getArea();
    box_out <<"   Your Area is: " << temp;
  //second box
    cout << "\n*-*-*Your second box*-*-*\n";
    box2.wrap();
  //file outout
    box_out << "   *-*-*Your second box!*-*-*";
    temp = box2.getLength();
    box_out << "   Your Length is: " << temp << "\n";
    temp = box2.getWidth();
    box_out << "   Your Width is: " << temp << "\n";
    temp = box2.define(box1.getLength(), box1.getWidth());
    if(temp == 1){
      box_out << "   You have a Square!";
    }else if(temp == 2){
      box_out << "   You have a Rectangle!";
    }
    temp = box2.getPerimeter();
    box_out <<"   Your Perimeter is: " << temp;
    temp = box2.getArea();
    box_out <<"   Your Area is: " << temp;
  //third box
    cout << "\n*-*-*Your third box*-*-*\n";
    box3.wrap();
  //file output
    box_out << "   *-*-*Your third box!*-*-*";
    temp = box3.getLength();
    box_out << "   Your Length is: " << temp << "\n";
    temp = box3.getWidth();
    box_out << "   Your Width is: " << temp << "\n";
    temp = box3.define(box1.getLength(), box1.getWidth());
    if(temp == 1){
      box_out << "   You have a Square!";
    }else if(temp == 2){
      box_out << "   You have a Rectangle!";
    }
    temp = box3.getPerimeter();
    box_out <<"   Your Perimeter is: " << temp;
    temp = box3.getArea();
    box_out <<"   Your Area is: " << temp;
  //fourth box
    cout << "\n*-*-*Your fourth box*-*-*\n";
    box4.wrap();
  //file output
    box_out << "   *-*-*Your fourth box!*-*-*";
    temp = box4.getLength();
    box_out << "   Your Length is: " << temp << "\n";
    temp = box4.getWidth();
    box_out << "   Your Width is: " << temp << "\n";
    temp = box4.define(box1.getLength(), box1.getWidth());
    if(temp == 1){
      box_out << "   You have a Square!";
    }else if(temp == 2){
      box_out << "   You have a Rectangle!";
    }
    temp = box4.getPerimeter();
    box_out <<"   Your Perimeter is: " << temp;
    temp = box4.getArea();
    box_out <<"   Your Area is: " << temp;
  //fifth box
    cout << "\n*-*-*Your fifth box*-*-*\n";
    box5.wrap();
  //file output
    box_out << "   *-*-*Your fifth box!*-*-*";
    temp = box5.getLength();
    box_out << "   Your Length is: " << temp << "\n";
    temp = box5.getWidth();
    box_out << "   Your Width is: " << temp << "\n";
    temp = box5.define(box1.getLength(), box1.getWidth());
    if(temp == 1){
      box_out << "   You have a Square!";
    }else if(temp == 2){
      box_out << "   You have a Rectangle!";
    }
    temp = box5.getPerimeter();
    box_out <<"   Your Perimeter is: " << temp;
    temp = box5.getArea();
    box_out <<"   Your Area is: " << temp;


    cout << "\n*-*-*User-defined box*-*-*\n";
    cout << "Enter your Length dimension"<<endl;
    cin >>temp;
    box6.setLength(temp);
    cout << "Enter your Width dimension"<<endl;
    cin >>temp;
    box6.setWidth(temp);

    box6.define(box6.getLength(),box6.getWidth());

    cout << "Perimeter of box is : " << box6.getPerimeter() <<endl;


    cout << "Area of Box is: " << box6.getArea() <<endl;



    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: _`friend std::ostream &operator << ( std::ostream &, Rectangle & );`_ should be `friend std::ostream &operator << ( std::ostream &, const Rectangle & );` in 1st place.

Comment: `void Rectangle:: wrap(){` should have a `std::ostream&` parameter instead of writing to `std::cout` . Same for `define()`. Weird function naming BTW.

Comment: Im afraid I don't quite follow, do you mean i need to write
 void Rectangle:: wrap(std::ostream&){

Comment: Yes, something like this would go into the right direction.

Comment: So when i change the wrap member function definition parameter from void to (std::ostream&). what do i do down in main, when calling box1.wrap() ?